# How to add multiple tab close event handlers to JavaFX Tab?

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, event-handling, eventhandler

JavaFX's [`Tab`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html) class provides a [`setOnClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setOnClosed-javafx.event.EventHandler-) method to add an event handler that is executed when the tab has been closed.

This works well when I only want to add a single event handler.
What I haven't achieved yet is to add multiple event handlers, since calling [`setOnClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setOnClosed-javafx.event.EventHandler-) a second time "overwrites" the event handler set on the first call.

In the following code example, only `doSomethingIsExecuted` is executed on tab close, yet I would like that all three event handlers are executed.

```
Tab tab = new Tab();
tab.setOnClosed(event -> doSomething());
tab.setOnClosed(event -> doSomethingElse());
tab.setOnClosed(event -> doSomethingIsExecuted());
```

*Additional info: It is not possible to combine the three event handlers into one in my case, I really need a solution to add multiple event handlers.*

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any API that lets you do this directly. I think the only options are 1. If you have access to the tab pane, register a listener with its list of tabs, so you can respond if a tab is removed from the list. You can register multiple listeners this way. 2. Set the handler to a handler that wraps any existing handler and invokes it, then performs the additional action. This is reasonably easy, but it would be difficult to remove any handlers this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a handler that invokes multiple handlers form a list:

```
List<EventHandler<Event>> closedEventHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
tab.setOnClosed(event -> {
    for (Iterator<EventHandler<Event>> iterator = closedEventHandlers.iterator(); !event.isConsumed() && iterator.hasNext();) {
        iterator.next().handle(event);
    }
});
```

If you don't have a place add the elements to the list you could use a helper method that stores the the list in the properties of `Tab`:

```
public final class TabUtils {
    private TabUtils() {}

    private static final String TAB_CLOSED_HANDLERS_KEY = "TabUtils.CLOSED_EVENT.list";

    public static void addClosedHandler(Tab tab, EventHandler<Event> handler) {
        List<EventHandler<Event>> handlers = (List<EventHandler<Event>>) tab.getProperties().get(TAB_CLOSED_HANDLERS_KEY);
        if (handlers == null) {
            // create & store new handler list and register handler
            handlers = new ArrayList<>();
            tab.getProperties().Put(TAB_CLOSED_HANDLERS_KEY, handlers);
            tab.setOnClosed(event -> {
                for (Iterator<EventHandler<Event>> iterator = handlers.iterator(); !event.isConsumed() && iterator.hasNext();) {
                    iterator.next().handle(event);
                }
            });
        }
        handlers.add(handler);
    }

    public static void removeClosedHandler(Tab tab, EventHandler<Event> handler) {
        List<EventHandler<Event>> handlers = (List<EventHandler<Event>>) tab.getProperties().get(TAB_CLOSED_HANDLERS_KEY);
        if (handlers != null) {
            if (handlers.remove(handler) && handlers.isEmpty()) {
                // remove handler list and handler if there are no more handlers
                tab.getProperties().remove(TAB_CLOSED_HANDLERS_KEY);
                tab.setOnClosed(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```